# HTTPS request in iOS 9 : NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)

Tags: ios, ios9

I'm updating my app to accommodate Apple's new [ATS](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/). Without any changes to the Plist-Info,the following code throws an error at `sendSynchronousRequest()` in a vanilla `iOS 9 simulator.

```
NSURL *url  =[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://Google.com"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request setURL:url];

NSURLResponse *urlResponse = nil;
NSError *error = nil;    
NSData *reponse = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                        returningResponse:&urlResponse
                                                    error:&error];
```

Error:

> NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)

Any thoughts as to what might be behind this issue?

*Ps*: I understand that `NSURLConnection` is deprecated. But this invocations works find if I add `AllowArbitraryLoads` in `Plist`.

Comment: Look in the Apple Forums, in Networking. I posted on this and got a good answer, as have others.

Comment: Couldn't find it. Can you please share the link?

Comment: This is the link: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/6452

Comment: Thanks for this link! Only "big hammer" approach mentioned in the forums worked for me :-) Maybe that's because I am using IP address instead of domain name for connecting.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)
corresponds to the server not supporting "Forward Secrecy".

To work around this, add a domain exception to .plist file as follows:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>test.testdomain.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Comment: After add above code in plist.. i'm getting same error   NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)
error=Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made."

Comment: i am still facing the issue , have you guys found the solution?

Comment: Doesn't work. Shall I use  test.testdomain.com or something like: test.testdomain.com/some/path/here

Comment: I faced same issue even after adding above steps.

Answer (score 9):

Add a new row in your plist file.

[image: Add a new row in your plist file]

Comment: Perfect. Worked for me. It was easier to update seeing your image. Thanks :D

Answer (score 6):

I added this code in the info.plist to allow any request http:

```
 <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

This article lists all the changes made by Apple for iOS 9 and their implementations:

http://ste.vn/2015/06/10/configuring-app-transport-security-ios-9-osx-10-11/

Comment: I am having this in plist info by default but still it fails

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to the info.plist file. And replace 'My_Base_Url.com' with your web service link's base url. This should do the trick.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>My_Base_Url.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.2</string>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSRequiresCertificateTransparency</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.2</string>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your app includes H5 page, sometimes it also will have this error.
It doesn't only require to turn on `Allow Arbitrary Loads` to fix it, but also require to add code below in your appDelegate.m:

```
@implementation NSURLRequest(ATS)
+ (BOOL)allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost:(NSString *)host
{
    return YES;
}
@end
```

Comment: How could I add it to my AppDelegate in xamarin forms ?

Comment: @Pxaml, not familiar with xamarin. The code implements a NSURLRequest category. You can check how to add a category in xamarin.

Answer (score 0):

According to this: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/36842#36842

The correct exception to fix HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802) is:

```
NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads
```

Comment: That case is interesting - thanks for sharing. In my case, this error was due to server not supporting forward secrecy. We ultimately fixed the cipher suite list in our server end to support FwSec and that fixed the app (and exception '..ExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy' was no longer needed).

Comment: Our case was due to having a self signed certificate in our test virtual machine.

Comment: @spirographer - so how did you get your self-signed certificate on your VM to work?

Comment: @ness-EE I totally recommend using https://letsencrypt.org/ now that they are launched.  That way you don't need any exceptions to support VM differently than production.