# How to authenticate the server with self signed certificate without using delegate methods in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, ssl, certificate

I want to authenticate the server with my self signed certificate without using the delegate methods as shown in [[Making HTTPS request in iOS 9 with self-signed certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32583303/5845233][1]) . For every https request, I want to authenticate using my certificate. What are the possible ways to achieve it?

Comment: Why without delegates?

Comment: I will be using swizzling mechanism for synchronous and asynchronous call for my dynamic libraries. Hence I should be able to establish authentication with this certificate without implementing the delegates.